# What's a good tool for speed benchmarking?

Tags: performance

I am doing some optimisation on my site and would like to take some readings on page load speed in order to determine what works and what not. Since my internet connection is unreliable I cannot just test on how long it takes to download the page to my laptop, but I need an external reliable source to test. Any good tools/websites that do this?

Comment: Off topic: while there may be a WordPress plugin for this, plugin recommendations are off-topic here. Anything else, and this wouldn't be about WordPress (try [Pro Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try either of these for your site, either one will guide you to better page load performance.

http://webpagetest.org

http://gtmetrix.com